# Same app UI on Android, IOS and Windows Phone

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, windows-phone

I am creating an app for all three platforms:android, ios and windows phone.
The app is ready for android and ios, on both platforms the UI is mostly the same.
Sadly I'm facing problems on windows phones.

How can I keep the Android UI design on a windows phone app ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a native application, it's a really bad practice to copy/paste your design over 3 very different UI! You'll always have problems with that!

If it's a Frameworks designed app (e.g Cordova, Titanium...) you surely can find help on dedicated forum.

Bests.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Its a native application for android written in Java and for ios written in objective c.

Comment: Well, i tried once to do the same things (client wish), and it was terrible!
I experienced many UI issue (pixel position, scale) and the Android density is very difficult to reproduce in another UI system (and vice/versa)!
You should use the native component, specific to each platform (better for memory, reusability...)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in this case is to use ***Xamarin*** and ***MvvCross*** (truly cross-platform MVVM ,but on C# framework).
Here's [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566191/MvvmCross-v-Writing-a-First-App) !